# <h2> tag is not aligning to the top of the image next to it in Outlook 2003 2007 20013

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble aligning the `<h2>` tag in the code below to the image next to it. It is appearing around 40pixels lower but only in older versions of Outlook. I have tried vertically aligning all elements with no luck. It appears correctly in other email clients and more recent versions of Outlook.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;" width="560" valign="top">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://images.adsttc.com/media/images/5b08/b87c/f197/ccb5/4900/00bd/medium_jpg/The_S_02_filter_edit2_06.jpg?1527298139" alt="Hani" width="120" height="210"
         border="0" align="left"></a>
      <h2 style="vertical-align: top; margin-top: 0px; padding-top: 0px;"><a href="#" style="vertical-align: top; margin-top: 0px; padding-top: 0px;">Eid for Refugees</a></h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
         dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.<a href="#">Donate now</a>.&nbsp;</p>
       <br></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: plase screenshot that outlook render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "simple" fix might be to add an other `<td>` element. You could also "nest" this as a new table into your existing one.

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top;" width="120" valign="top"><a href="#"><img src="https://images.adsttc.com/media/images/5b08/b87c/f197/ccb5/4900/00bd/medium_jpg/The_S_02_filter_edit2_06.jpg?1527298139" alt="Hani" width="120" height="210" border="0" align="left"></a>
</td>
<td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;" width="440" valign="top">
<h2 style="vertical-align: top; margin-top: 0px; padding-top: 0px;"><a href="#" style="vertical-align: top; margin-top: 0px; padding-top: 0px;">Eid for Refugees</a></h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.<a href="#">Donate now</a>.&nbsp;</p>
<br></td>
</tr>
</table>
```